# What would the name and formula be for Mo+O+Se?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I do cross-stitch and want to spell the word "moose" (for a project focusing on the animal) with squares from the periodic table and present a compound formula and name that encapsulates all three elements, Mo+O+Se, in that order. I'm not looking for strictly realistic chemistry, just a formula and a name that would work IF the compound had actually existed. The number of atoms of each element is up to you. Can you help me with a formula and a name for Molybdenum + Oxygen + Selenium?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Chemistry question and pertains to wordplay which doesn't fit in this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [molybdenum oxysulfide](https://www.google.com/search?q=molybenum+oxysulfide) is apparently a real compound with the formula $\ce{MoOS2}$ or $\ce{MoO2S}$.  Since selenium is a chalcogen and has (some) chemistry that is analogous to sulfur, I think ***molybdenum oxyselenide*** would be an appropriate choice.

More formally:

1. [Molybdenum(IV) oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum(IV)_oxide) is a compound with the formula $\ce{MoO2}$.
2. [Molybdenum(IV) selenide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum_diselenide), also called molybdenum diselenide, has a formula of $\ce{MoSe2}$
3. [Molybdenum sulfide selenide](http://www.2dsemiconductors.com/2d-semiconductors/mosse/) exists and has the approximate formula $\ce{MoSSe}$.

Thus, perhaps ***molybdenum(IV) oxide selenide*** would be another choice.

Comment: Wonderful, Curt, thank you! And would that simply make the formula MoOSe? (Please forgive my cluelessness!)

Comment: So, Curt F., with the edits to the original answer, can I assume that I can go with at least one of the following three combos? Molybdenum oxyselenide (MoOSe), or Molybdenum dioxyselenide (MoO2Se), or Molybdenum oxydiselenide (MoOSe2)? (And again, please forgive my cluelessness!)

Comment: Material Scientists and Engineers would likely use the latter  ***molybdenum(IV) oxide selenide*** in publication so I would go with that.

Comment: And what would the formula for that be?

Comment: The formula would be MoOSe.  Isn't that what you were asking for?